# unable to import main js file on a component

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

In my laravel vuejs project I have a resource folder, a js folder, and a component folder.

Inside the component folder I have another folder which is named 
secondslide it is like `resource/js/components/secondslide/SecondTabmenue.vue`.

on my secondTabmenue.vue I want to import app.js which is in `resource/js/app.js.`

I have imported app.js like this:

```
import {eventBus} from "../app.js";
```

but it's not working. what should be the right way to do this?

[image]

Comment: What is the error ? 
Could you share your app.js file ?

Comment: I belive that app.js is the main JS here, if not than thats okay. have you tried this?
 `import {eventBus} from "./../app.js";`

Comment: i tried this on that day. and that worked. thank you anyway